# Implement check availability functionality on save button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a link button in aspx form which check availablity of login email address and its functionality is as.

```
    protected void lnkCheckAvailable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SystemUserBL bl = new SystemUserBL(SessionContext.SystemUser);
        ds = new DataSet();
        bl.FetchForLoginEmailAddress(ds, txtLoginEmailAddress.Text);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            valDuplicatePassword.Visible = true;
            valDuplicatePassword.Text = "<b>This User Name is already in use by another user.</b>";
        }
        else
         {
            valDuplicatePassword.Visible = true;
            valDuplicatePassword.Text = "<b>Congratulations! " + txtLoginEmailAddress.Text + " is available.</b>";
        }
    }
```

It's working fine when user will click on check availability link button. There is another button "Save" which saves the user information in the table. Now my issue is that if it displays "This User Name is already in use by another user." message the information is still saved in the database. Please tell me how to prevent this!!!

Comment: Why do you have this as two separate actions? A username *may* be available when you do the "Check Availability" check but may have been taken by *someone else* by the time you "Save". I can't think of any advantage of running a separate check first.

Comment: Simply disable your save button in your If block.
If you want to check the user login email in the save time, As @Demien_The_Undeliever said, you can do a check in the save action and thoow an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can return `true` or `false` based on user name exists in database or not. You can create a method which will check user availability.

When user press save button you will call that method if method returns `true` it means user exists.

```
private bool CheckUserAvailability()
{
        SystemUserBL bl = new SystemUserBL(SessionContext.SystemUser);
        ds = new DataSet();
        bl.FetchForLoginEmailAddress(ds, txtLoginEmailAddress.Text);

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            valDuplicatePassword.Visible = true;
            valDuplicatePassword.Text = "<b>This User Name is already in use by another user.</b>";
            return true;
            }
            else
             {
              valDuplicatePassword.Visible = true;
              valDuplicatePassword.Text = "<b>Congratulations! " + txtLoginEmailAddress.Text + " is available.</b>";
              return false;
            }
 }
```

You can also call this method on `link` click.

```
protected void lnkCheckAvailable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CheckUserAvailability();
}
```

You will call this method on `Save` button if user don't exist than save information in database.

```
protected void Savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(CheckUserAvailability() == false)
   {
    SaveUserInfoToDataBase();
   }
}
```

Comment: All of these pre-checks are pointless, as I've said, if there's any possibility that two users may both attempt to run this code at the same time. E.g. both users check availability - yes, it's available. Both users press "Save". The code runs for both users and determines that the username is available and *then* presses ahead and inserts both users. You *have* to have a check at the actual point of `INSERT` into the database (and also, preferable, a unique constraint to prevent duplicates) and most pre-checks are then rendered pointless.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes exactly i agree with you but this answer is in OP's context. You have already pointed in comments you can also edit answer if you like.